# VueJS - How to define routes for any number of optional parameters in Vue Router

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I a have tree navigation with categories, subcategories and products. I need to define two routes, for categories and for product. There can be multiple nested subcategories.

I wanna show the same component for e.g. `/category` and `/category/subcategory/subcategory/subcategory` as well.

Product route will looks like `category/product/productslug` or `category/subcategory/subcategory/subcategory/product/productslug` where `product` is prefix before specific product slug.

In Laravel I did something like this:

For Product:

```
Route::get('/{category?}/product/{slug}', 'ProductController@getProductBySlug')->where('category', '.*');
```

For Category:

```
Route::get('/{category?}', 'CategoryController@getCategoryBySlug')->where('category', '.*');
```

In Vue Router doesn't work smth like this:

```
routes: [
 {path: '/', component: HomeView},
 {path: '*/product/:slugproduct', component: ProductView},
 {path: '*', component: CategoryView},
]
```

Answer (score 2):

I have created a [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZwWjvV) for you to test the correct solution to your task. Now, let me explain how it works. Vue-Router has magic reg-exp patterns that can be awesome, more info [on GitHub in path-to-regexp project](https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp#unnamed-parameters).

Just change your `*` to `(.*)` and here your go - just works. To get the pattern group from actual params you can use `this.$route.params.pathMatch` which will contain current reg-exp group, other named params that were described in your path will be available with there actual names - `id`, `slug` etc.

As you can see I have pushed a custom route `/category/subcategory/subcategory/product/100`, and console output will look like this:

```
Vue mounted...
Home component mounted...
path: /category/subcategory/subcategory/product/100
tree: /category/subcategory/subcategory
id: 100
```

As you can see we have reg-exp `(.*)` group as expected and an `id` param.

```js
const Home = {
  data() {
    return { };
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log('Home component mounted...');
    console.log('path: ' + this.$route.path);
    console.log('tree: ' + this.$route.params.pathMatch);
    console.log('id: ' + this.$route.params.id);
  },
  template: `<div>Home component...</div>`
};

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'hash',
  routes: [
    {
      path: '(.*)/product/:id',
      name: 'index',
      component: Home,
    }
  ]
})

const vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  data: {},
  mounted() {
    console.log('Vue mounted...');
  }
})

router.push("/category/subcategory/subcategory/product/100");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue-router/3.0.2/vue-router.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.22/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```